# Adding firebase for flutter project isn't working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I followed several tutorials to add firebase to my flutter project. But no matter what I do, my project throws an error with the same exact failure.

I tried creating new projects and got the same exact failure.

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syvlBdx4zlc).

After making the changes and entering command `flutter run`, this gives me the same error again and again.

Output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ASUS X00TD in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.5/auto-value-annotations-1.6.5.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.5/auto-value-annotations-1.6.5.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.5/auto-value-annotations-1.6.5.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-parent:1.6.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-parent/1.6.5/auto-value-parent-1.6.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin
                        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:7.
                           > Could not load module metadata from /home/techmirtz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.google.auto/auto-parent/7/475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08/descriptor.bin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.techmirtz.easynotes"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
```

`android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @Yash I am afraid to tell you that it's throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

below code in flutter app -> android -> settings.gradle

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

If Helpful, don't forget to upvote.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that it's throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I played with the version of `build.gradle` in `android/build.gradle`

Under dependencies

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

OR

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

Similarly, try changing version of `firebase plugins`.

Comment: So does change the version of the dependencies and plugins worked out for you?